# Zookeeper not raising event for data change for a node but raising event for deleting that node

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

---

I am using zookeeper for process coordination. I set the ephemeral nodes with data as RUNNING and COMPLETE. So once a process crashes in RUNNING state, other replica should take over but in case of COMPLETE state replica should see this as COMPLETE, other replicas need not to take any action as its complete. But the problem is when I set the status COMPLETE and remove the ephemeral node by calling delete node API , Status COMPLETE change events is not received to replica but node deletion event is received to other replicas and though delete  event for that node is created to other replicas but generated event  contains data as RUNNING(which is expected to be COMPLETE) . Though Data on that ephemeral node is set before deleting the node. What could be the issue as I am using TreeCache for event watcher

Sample code : 
Earlier i was using changing data on node and deleting the same node as follows:

```
zkClient.setData().forPath(path, status.getBytes());
zkClient.delete().forPath(path);
```

Due to this i was getting event for Delete in watcher but was missing NODE_UPDATE event and event NODE_REMOVED event and data in the event for the node was older one. 
To avoid this I remove the line zkClient.delete().forPath(path) and invoking the delete on getting the event NODE_UPDATED .

Updated Watcher code :

```
  @Override
    public void childEvent(CuratorFramework client, TreeCacheEvent event) throws Exception {
        if (event.getData() == null) {
            return;
        }


        String path =  event.getData().getPath();
        String data = new String(event.getData().getData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        switch (event.getType()) {
            case NODE_ADDED: {
                LOGGER.debug("Node added: " + ZKPaths.getNodeFromPath(path));
                 break;
            }

            case NODE_UPDATED: {
                LOGGER.debug("Node changed: " + ZKPaths.getNodeFromPath(path));

                LOGGER.debug("Nodes deleting: " + path);
                zkCoordinationService.deleteNodes(path);
                break;
            }

            case NODE_REMOVED: {
                LOGGER.debug("Node removed: " + path);
                if ("RUNNING".equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                    publishChangeEvent(event, data);
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now its working fine without any lock and deleting the node after getting the event for status change. This way I am not loosing events also. What do you say about this approach.

Comment: Can you provide sample code?

Comment: @Randgalt I was using zookeeper distributed lock thinking that there may be race condition. But as read more, all writes are via master and atomic , I removed the locks . To avoid missing of the events  , i removed deletion of nodes after updating status .  I am updating the code snippet.

Comment: @Randgalt With the above code changes ,  its working fine without any lock and deleting the node after getting the event for status change in Watcher. This way I am not loosing events also. What do you say about this approach.

Comment: FWIW - it's not possible to get every event in ZooKeeper (though a a new feature I've added to the upcoming 3.6 will help). When a watcher triggers in ZK it is cleared and must be manually reset. In that time another process can add/change/remove the ZNode multiple times and your client will never know.